# Send a message to discord channels via google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, discord

I am using some scripts to send message to discord via google apps script... I used a function such as :

```
function postMessageToDiscord(){

  message = "Hello World!";

  var discordUrl = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/XXXXX";
  var payload = JSON.stringify({content: message});

  var params = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    method: "POST",
    payload: payload,
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordUrl, params);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Everything was working perfectly for weeks, but since 2 or 3 weeks, nothing is sent to discord anymore... Could someone help me to understand what's going on?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the following modifications?

### Pattern 1:

#### From:

```
var params = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  method: "POST",
  payload: payload,
  muteHttpExceptions: true
};
```

#### To:

```
var params = {
  method: "POST",
  payload: payload,
  muteHttpExceptions: true,
  contentType: "application/json"
};
```

### Pattern 2:

#### From:

```
var payload = JSON.stringify({content: message});
```

#### To:

```
var payload = {content: message};
```

### Note:

- In my environment, I could confirm that both patterns works fine while the error of `{"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}` occurs when your script is run.
- If your webhook cannot be used, how about setting it again? [Ref](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks)

### References:

- [Intro to Webhooks](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks)
- [Webhook Resource](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

If this was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Comment: @Maxence Hermand Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Interesting. This worked for me when I changed Pattern 1, but NOT Pattern 2. When I changed both Patterns I got a 404 error message.

Regardless, you got me where I needed to be in order to post simple messages to discord via webhook from my Google Spreadsheet script. Thanks!